# Share object instance between objects with Swinject

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

I am starting to use `Swinject` in my apps and I want to share an instance of my rootNavigator between `presenters`(Viper/MVP) or `viewControllers`(Not Viper). The main problem that I have is that I want to share `appRootNavigator` in `presenters`, but I loose the instance of `window` because when I register a new module `swinject` generates a new instance of that class (`AppRootNavigator`). How can I share `AppRootNavigator` between `presenters`.

In this part of the code, I try to change the `navigator` of the `presenter`, but it never goes into the if.

```
if let presenter = container.resolve(SignupPresenter.self, argument: self){
     signUpController.presenter = presenter
}
```

I don't know another way to do that.

This is the `rootNavigator`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Swinject

class AppRootNavigator: RootNavigator {

    internal let container: Container
    fileprivate var window: UIWindow?

    init(container: Container) {
        self.container = container
    }

    fileprivate lazy var storyboards: Storyboard = {
        return Storyboard(container: self.container)
    }()

    func installRootViewController(in window:UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
        currentNavigationController = signupController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = currentNavigationController
    }

    fileprivate func signupController() -> UINavigationController {
        let signUpController  =  storyboards.signup.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SignupController

        if let presenter = container.resolve(SignupPresenter.self, argument: self) {
            signUpController.presenter = presenter
        }
        return UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: signUpController)
    }
```

Here I register all elements I want to use.

```
import Swinject
import Alamofire
import RealmSwift

struct SignupContainer: Bundle {
    func create(_ container: Container) {

        container.register(SignupNavigator.self) { c in
            AppRootNavigator.init(container: container) as SignupNavigator
        }

        container.register(SignupInteractor.self) { c in
            SignupInteractorImpl(facebook: c.resolve(FacebookService.self)!,
                                 api: c.resolve(API.self)!,
                                 realm: c.resolve(Realm.self)!,
                                 analytics: c.resolve(Tracker.self)!)
        }

        container.register(SignupPresenter.self) { c, navigator in
            SignupPresenterImpl(navigator: navigator, interactor:c.resolve(SignupInteractor.self)!) as SignupPresenter
        }

        container.registerForStoryboard(SignupController.self) {
            c, controller in
            if var presenter = c.resolve(SignupPresenter.self, argument: c.resolve(SignupNavigator.self)!) {
                controller.presenter  = presenter
                presenter.view        = controller
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

To make your change of `navigator` in `presenter` work, you need to explicitly specify the argument type:

```
if let presenter = container.resolve(SignupPresenter.self, argument: self as SignupNavigator) {
    signUpController.presenter = presenter
}
```

However, you shouldn't need to do this. All you need is to register your `SignupNavigator` in `.container` object scope:

```
container.register(SignupNavigator.self) { c in                   
    AppRootNavigator.init(container: container) as SignupNavigator
}.inObjectScope(.container)
```